# How to remap the 'Alt gr' key on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard

In the past, pressing my <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key did the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>. Now, pressing my <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key did the same as <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

I don't understand why it changed. How can I cancel this change ?

I probably use a keyboard shortcut. *(Like alt + shift to switch from AZERTY to QWERTY)*

Comment: This would normally be an option of the keyboard layout. Though it should be hard to change it accidentally. Did you change anything else in that regard?

Comment: I did not change anything voluntarily. I was writing when it happened. I probably use a keyboard shortcut. (Like alt + shift to switch from AZERTY to QWERTY)

Comment: Without installing special tools and without editing the registry the only way to change the behavior of ALTGR system-wide is by changing the keyboard layout.

Comment: Is it possible to change the keyboard layout without go to the registry or go to the control panel?

Comment: Do you see a country code like "ENG" or "US" on the right side of your taskbar?

Comment: I see 'FR Français (France)'.(It's normal I'm French)

Comment: I found something strange : https://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/922646Clavier.png
Do you know what is "Ink Correction" ?

Comment: The problem was resolved by itself...

 But I would like somebody to explain to me what happened in case it happened again

Comment: This question is answered at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229633/how-to-globally-map-altgr-key-to-alt-key#396859

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally disabled AltGr functionality too.  After searching for a while, I found the following post:

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-do-i-enable-or-disable-alt-gr-key-on-windows-10-keyboard

Try pressing Shift+AltGr to toggle between different AltGr functions.  Hopefully this solves your issue.